# PHP connect to HTTPS site through proxy

Tags: php, curl, https, proxy

I've got the following problem: there is an HTTPS web site, and I need to connect to it through a proxy. Here are my cURL setopts:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '100.100.100.100:8080');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $ua);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

echo curl_error($ch);
```

outputs Failed connect to ######.com:8080; No error

Where 100.100.100.100:8080 is a placeholder for a valid HTTPS proxy. This doesn't work. How do I make cURL connect to an HTTPS website through a proxy? I would really like a soultion that would work through not only HTTPS proxies. Also, I would best prefer a method using cURL, but if there is a better way to do it, without cURL, I could use it instead.

Comment: Does the proxy require authentication?

Comment: You have to add output of `curl_error()`

Comment: @SquareCat: the proxy doesn't require authentication.

Comment: @hindmost: it says Failed connect to ######.com:8080; No error

Comment: 'outputs Failed connect to ######.com:8080; No error' ; does it mean your destination URL contains '8080' too? (I'm not talking of the proxy URL, but of the $url variable)

Comment: @Pascal Le Merrer: no, it doesn't. The URL is standart, beginning with https:// and ending with / .

Comment: It's surprising you have "######.com:8080" as an error message in this case, if you provided an IP address for the proxy, and not a domain name, and if $url does not contains a port. The error message would be a mix of the domain name and the proxy port???

Comment: @Pascal Le Merrer: yes, I noticed that now, too. Also, when I replace the proxy port with another, it shows in the error. Does this mean that somehow cURL tries to connect to the site on the same port that the proxy uses to accept connections?

Comment: I think I've got it, I've updated my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**
Add

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
```

It will prevent your HTTP proxy to parse your request headers and to act more transparently - like a tunnel.

---

initial answer, not interesting

Your code looks OK, and I assume you checked the trivial issues, so the problem is probably that the SSL certificate verification fails. It's the case if the certificate is self signed by example.
Try

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

to allow a request that allows using a self signed certificate.

Comment: When replacing the CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER in my original code with this line, it crashes with the following error: Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context

Comment: @Pascal Le Merrer It is the same as `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);`

Comment: Forget my answer, your parameter has already the value I suggested. Sorry.

Comment: Concerning your update: the error changed, it is now as follows:
error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol

Comment: It's the kind of response you have when making an http request to an https server...

Comment: It could be a problem with the domain name resolution. You could try to replace the domain name with it's IP address. Use NSlookup to get it.

Comment: really, so a normal response when connecting to an https server is an error? =P And yes, the page won't get loaded, so the problem still persists. Changing to another proxy gives "Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to #####.com:7808" (the proxy used is with the 7808 port, so the proxy tunneling thing sort of didn't work)

Comment: I changed the url to $url = "https://<site's IP>/<path>/"; and now it still doesn't load ><