# how to use proxy in ssl curl

Tags: php, ssl, curl

i can use ssl curl in php with out problem but when set proxy i can't open site

this example i hope to get help

```
$url="https://www.digicert.com";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) .'/cert.pem'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAPATH, dirname(__FILE__) .'/cert.pem'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__) .'./cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "cookiename=0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY,'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080');
echo curl_exec($ch);
var_dump(curl_error($ch));


echo "curl_errno: ".curl_errno($ch)."<br>"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP connect to HTTPS site through proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22267226/php-connect-to-https-site-through-proxy)

Comment: @ Andrej Ludinovskov it's same my problem but all comments not have solved question to now

Comment: Can anyone of the developers help me